# Using GPMC dll without installing GPMC product

Tags: c#, dll, console, group-policy

I'm developing a c# application that compares the current computer's GPO with the recommended.
It should be a "light" app that runs on many computers with no installation.

In order to read the computer's GPO, i used "Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management.dll" (it works well).

I copied the exe and the dlls to a folder in another computer, when i run it i get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.GroupPolicy.ServerAdminTools.GpmgmtLib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Is it possible to use the GPMC dlls without having the GPMC product installed?

[Eyal.](http://reginiano.com)

Comment: Did you try copying the dependency dll too?

Comment: I copied all of the group policy dlls from C:\Windows\winsxs.
How do i know what are the dll's dependencies?

Comment: I'd start with the dll in the error message - GpmgmtLib.

Comment: I already copied it.

Comment: Is it a COM library? If so it may need to be registered with regasm.exe. You might also need to use Process Monitor to see what assemblies your application is trying to load.

Comment: It's not a COM library.
I just checked with ".NET Reflector" and found out that the 'Microsoft.GroupPolicy.ServerAdminTools.GpmgmtLib.dll' has only 1 dependency- 'mscorlib.dll' (.net framework, which is installed).

This is really strange, because everything seems to be there... :(
Maybe it relies on the GPMC installation?